# Firefox Add-on SDK: Communicate and add listeners to page script objects

Tags: javascript, callback, firefox-addon-sdk

I am about to write an page-modification add-on that needs to communicate to JavaScript APIs defined on the page by calling functions and adding listeners to them. The [page script interaction article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) at the MDN only lists possibilities to copy pretty primitive data and functions between add-on and page script. The only possible solution I can see is the "permissions": { "unsafe-content-script": true } option in the package.json to allow direct access to the page script.

What is the best way to get actual access to the pages JavaScript objects?
Do I have to fear that Firefox will no longer support my add-on in the future if I use unsafe-content-scripts?

In my specific case I would like to get access to the IRC chat interface inside of the Ember.js application [Twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/). I would like to use it's message sending functionality and add a listener to receive messages. Directly copied into the developer console, the following commands would do such a thing for example:

```
var chat = require('web-client/models/room').default.instances.<channel name>.tmiRoom;
chat.on('message', function(msg) {
    if (/hi|hello|greetings/i.test(msg.message)) {
        chat.sendMessage('Have a nice day '+ msg.from +'!');
    }
});
```